# VB 2015 build error: Conflicting options specified: Win32 resource file; Win32 manifest

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a vb.net WinForms project that was originally developed in VS2010, and I'm now trying to work on in VS2015.  However, without changing anything, VS2015 will not compile it.  It initially returned 2 errors:

```
Error   BC2023  cannot specify both /win32icon and /win32resource
Error   BC37216 Conflicting options specified: Win32 resource file; Win32 manifest
```

I could (temporarily) get rid of the first one by removing the icon specified in Project properties > Application > Icon.  But I can't see how to eliminate the second.  Googling the second error seems to return nothing meaningful at all.

The error message clearly comes from the VB compiler itself, but I'm not aware, using the IDE, how to "specify" either a manifest or a resource file.  I presume the manifest accessed by clicking on Project properties > Application > View Windows Settings is the manifest it refers to.  However even temporarily deleting this file had no effect.

Is there any way to resolve this build error?

Comment: These compile options are not exposed in the IDE.  Look in the .vbproj file with, say, Notepad.

Comment: Thanks - just deleting the resource entry in there did indeed fix it